# Zomato api is not working in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, zomato-api

I need to get the review of a particular restaurant using [Zomato Api](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation) in Nodejs.But this api is working in **postman** .

[image: postman response]

But it is not working in **Nodejs**.

[image: Nodejs response]
**app.js**

```
var https = require('https');
var request = require('request');
var zomatoUserKey = '****************************';
var postheaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'user-key': zomatoUserKey
};
var optionspost = {
  host: 'developers.zomato.com', // here only the domain name
  path: 'api/v2.1/reviews', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
  headers: postheaders,
  method: 'POST',
  data: '{"res_id": "zoma.to/r/34343"}'
};
https.request(optionspost, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log('error', error);
  console.log('body', body);
  console.log('response', response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation of Zomato API](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation) you need to use `GET` request instead of `POST`.

```
var optionspost = {
  host: 'developers.zomato.com', // here only the domain name
  path: '/api/v2.1/reviews', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
  headers: postheaders,
  method: 'GET',
  // -------^----
  data: '{"res_id": "zoma.to/r/34343"}'
};
```